# Why won't this fragment transaction work?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having trouble with this fragment transaction. I tried using a toast message in place of the editData function and it worked fine. Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.edit:
        editData();
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void editData() {
    EditFragment fragment = new EditFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.groupName);
    String groupName = tv.getText().toString();
    args.putString(EditFragment.ARG_GROUPNAME, groupName);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_info, fragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);

    transaction.commit();
}
```

Here is the logcat:

```
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353): Process: com.john.oper, PID: 21353
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at com.john.oper.EditFragment.onCreateView(EditFragment.java:29)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-03 00:25:11.565: E/AndroidRuntime(21353):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the onCreateView of the EditFragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    Bundle data = getArguments();
    EditText et = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.groupName);
    et.setText(data.getString(ARG_GROUPNAME));

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit, container, false);
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? Exception? If so, post the logcat.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: But what are the symptoms of your problem? If you can't tell us, how can we know?

Comment: Ecxeption is thrown in code you didnt post: com.john.oper.EditFragment.onCreateView(EditFragment.java:29). Post code to your EditFragment

Comment: You are getting a null pointer exception in your EditFragment.  What is the code on line 29 in your OnCreateView method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't setting your arguments to the fragment.

```
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

So you're crashing when you try to do a get string on the fragment arguments.

Edit: Also, you're trying to access the fragment's view (`getView()`) in `onCreateView()`, which is where the view is being created, so it will be null. You should defer that logic to `onViewCreated()` instead.

Comment: I fixed that but it still isn't working for some reason

Comment: Looking at the logcat there is a NullPointerException: EditText et = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.groupName);

Comment: Thanks a million this woeks now but for some reason the original fragment can still be seen in the background. Do you know why this might be??